# delete mysql: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I have delete query, but it returned error [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax
please help

```
DELETE FROM app_files tiko
where tiko.doc_type_id = 2102 and  tiko.application_id IN
(SELECT c.id FROM cus_app c 
WHERE c.`app_date`>='2017-01-27 00:01:01' AND c.`app_status` IN ('accepted'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not add alias if you are using DELETE FROM table, use table name directly.

Answer (score 0):

No `FROM`:

```
DELETE app_files tiko
where tiko.doc_type_id = 2102 and
      tiko.application_id IN (SELECT c.id
                              FROM cus_app c 
                              WHERE c.`app_date`>='2017-01-27 00:01:01' AND
                                    c.`app_status` IN ('accepted')
                             );
```

Or . . .

```
delete tiko from app_files tiko
    . . .;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM app_files 
where doc_type_id = 2102 and  application_id IN
(SELECT c.id FROM cus_app c 
WHERE c.`app_date`>='2017-01-27 00:01:01' AND c.`app_status` IN ('accepted'))
```